# Excel on Sum every n rows

Tags: excel

I want to add 10 every 9th row in Column A. It should look like the image below. Can I get some quick help please.

Thanks in Advance
~T

[image]

Comment: Got two good answers, but I couldn't tell from the image whether you wanted 8 1's followed by 8 11's or 8 1's followed by 9 11's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A1** enter `1` and in **A2** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),8)-1=0,A1+10,A1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

This approach allows the ability to put the arbitrary starting value in **A1** and the increment and repeat factor in the formula.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and Perfect.

Comment: I could be wrong about my interpretation of the question!

Comment: @TomSharpe  I assumed groups of **8** items................that why I editted my answer.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Thanks anyways , the format was more important to me. I modified according to my  need :)

Answer (score 2):

Put this formula in cell A1 and fill down

```
=FLOOR.MATH(ROW()/9)*10+1
```

this version is more versatile:

```
=FLOOR.MATH((ROW()-5+1)/9)*10+3
```

**5** is the starting row (so start the formula in the 5th row) and **3** is the startingnumber. Adjust these values as needed.

Comment: gives me an 'Invalid Name Error'

Comment: In *Excel* you need:  `=FLOOR(ROW()/9,1)*10+1`

Comment: @Gary's Student FLOOR.MATH is supported in excel 2013 and up. In 2010 and older you should use FLOOR.

Comment: I like the second formula a lot *(+1)*

Comment: So the second formula would be =FLOOR((ROW()-1)/8,1)*10+1 in the earlier version of Excel to repeat 8 times starting from row 1 with start value of 1.

Comment: My bad. I should have mentioned i am using Excel 2010. But thank you. I will store the formula for future use.