# Excel - autofill copied cells by custom increment

Tags: vba, excel, increment

The following table is given:

```
.  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q
9  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1
```

Kinde simple task.
In tbl2 ill do the following in a cell:

```
='tbl1'!A1
```

Now, if I use the excel-autofill function the cell on the right will get this

```
='tbl1'!B1
```

But i would like to have F1. So I set the cell next to it manually to

```
='tbl1'!F1
```

... selected both and wanted to use the autofill again, hoping it would recognize the increment of 5 instead using the normal 1.

But it doesn't work.
Of course the next cell should contain the value of tbl1'K1.

Is there any function to achieve this, or any workaround using VBA?

I know that this question isn't really worth asking, but I'm pretty sure that this is possible. I just forgot how to do it.

Note I am coping the files from tbl1 to tbl2.

EDIT (in a nutshell):
- Data is in tbl1, row 9 starts on column A.
- Copying these files from tbl1 into tbl2.
-> tbl2 Column B row 2 shall contain A9.
->B3 shall contain the data from 'tbl1'!F9. (so skip next 4 cols)

Comment: Can you give a screenshot, I really do not understand what is this tbl1?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it stands for table1. The tabs on the bottom side of each excel sheet. The first is called tbl1 or table1. and the second one is tbl2 (table2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification it needs pull data from row 9 of "tbl1" sheet

try this formula in any cell of tbl2 column "B"

```
=OFFSET('tbl1'!$A$9,0,(COLUMNS($B:B)-1)*5)
```

and then go with autofill

should you need to begin from any different column than "B", then just adapt that `$B:B` to the new column index

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("tbl1!"&ADDRESS(9,FLOOR(COLUMN()-2/1,1)*5+1))
```

Enter this formula in any row of `Column A` and drag it across.

`FLOOR` formula is derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980016/excel-on-sum-every-n-rows).

Comment: I tryed it, but it doesn't work. Can u please explain the formular, maybe i'm using it wrong.

Comment: @E.Coil - In which cell are you entering this formula?

Comment: @E.Coil - `INDIRECT` function takes a string and returns the reference. `ADDRESS` function obtains the address when row and column number are provided.

Comment: @E.Coil - So `ADDRESS` function gives the address of first row and column number after incrementing column by 5. And this address is provided to `INDIRECT` function with `tbl1` to get the value.

Comment: @E.Coil - see my edited formula enter this formula in cell B2 of tbl2.

Comment: @E.Coil - I've changed row number to 9 as you mentioned in your edit.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Unfortunately it doesn't work, sorry

Comment: @E.Coil - Are you entering above formula in `Cell B2` of `tbl2`?

Comment: I figured out the row, but still doesn't work. I get #NAME? as an error. @Mrig i entered it into B2 tbl2 as u said

Comment: @E.Coil - I've tested this formula it works for me. Can you share screen shot or something.

Comment: @E.Coil - or else try this one `=INDIRECT("'tbl1!'"&ADDRESS(9,FLOOR(COLUMN()-2/1,1)*5+1))`